# Specify different spacing between arrangedSubviews of stackview

Tags: swift, autolayout, uistackview

I have my login view designed with stackview. The stackview has five views(segmented control, two textfields, and two buttons)

I set the alignment as Fill and distribution to be Fill proportionally. However, I can not change the spacing between the subViews.

[image]

Right now the spacing is 10 but I want 20 spacing between the segmented control and the first textField and 5 spacing between the "Sign In" button and the "Forgot Password?" button.

I know I can just remove the stackviews and use auto layout to achieve my desired positioning but I want to use stackview to control the views during the rotations.

Can anyone please help me with this.

[image]

Comment: You can't. This is no option to provide different spacing between views inside the stackView. You can alternatively move the segmentControl and "Forgot Password?" button out of the stackView.

Comment: @Natasha you may have to manage from your side with your own logic. I will provide you one way you have to take UIView and in side the UIView you have to add your other controls that you need to use. and set ui view background colour clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UIStackView** has an instance method that applies custom spacing after the specified view.

```
func setCustomSpacing(_ spacing: CGFloat, 
                after arrangedSubview: UIView)
```

---

```
stackView.setCustomSpacing(20, after: segmenteControl)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well what you can do is to add cushion view in stackView to get more space between two views ... clear that cushion view background color and fix its height accoeding to your. demand